# How to make menu items localizable using ABP and Nebular

Tags: angular, typescript, abp, nebular

I'm building an application based on ABP framework version 4.4. I'm changing the default basic theme of ABP to Nebular. I've encountered many issues and one of them is localizing menu items. In HTML we type `{{ '::Menu:Home' | abpLocalization }}` for localization but this doesn't work in Nebular. For example:

```js
import { NbMenuItem } from '@nebular/theme';

export const MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: '"::Menu:Home" | abpLocalization',
    icon: 'home-outline',
    link: '/',
    home: true,
  },
];
```

I've inserted the ABP localization pipe to the title property but the plain text `"::Menu:Home" | abpLocalization` is displayed on the UI. I know that Nebular's menu title property accepts only string then how to localize menu items? Please suggest some workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the [localization *service*](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Localization#using-the-localization-service), to translate the keys before you're passing them to the menu component:

```js
import {
  LocalizationService
} from '@abp/ng.core';

class MyClass {
  public readonly MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [{
    title: this.localizationService.instant('::Menu:Home'),
    icon: 'home-outline',
    link: '/',
    home: true,
  }];

  constructor(private localizationService: LocalizationService) {}
}
```

This does mean, however, that you can't simply export a `const` from the file's root.

So, for your case, this should work:

```
import { Component. OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalizationService } from '@abp/ng.core';
import { MENU_ITEMS } from './pages-menu';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-sidebar-menu',
    template:  <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu> ,
    styleUrls: ['./sidebar-menu.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    menu: NbMenuItem[];

    constructor(private localizationService: LocalizationService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const menuTranslated = [...MENU_ITEMS];
        menuTranslated.forEach(item => item.title = this.localizationService.instant(item.title));
        this.menu = menuTranslated;
    }
}
```

In `./pages_menu`, you'll just build your menu with the translation keys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I access menu items from other components? E.g.: I have a sidebar-menu.component in which I exported MENU_ITEMS const. Now what adjustments I have to make? The sidebar-menu.component's code is `import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MENU_ITEMS } from './pages-menu';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-menu',
  template: `
    <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar-menu.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarMenuComponent {
  menu = MENU_ITEMS;
}
`

Comment: @Dias170497 I've updated my answer